# display popover on hover for every Material UI table row and box shadow issue

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I'm working on react app and I'm using React v18.2 and Material UI V5

I created a simple table with an MUI Table component and I want to display a popover for every table row when a mouse pointer hovers on a specific table row

I ended up with add a simple popover component to the last cell of each row

also, I added a slide In animation to my popover component

The problem is when the animation is being played. A horizontal scroll is added to my table

How can I remove the scroll bar?

my simple table:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wood-ix9n41?file=/demo.tsx)

my second question: how can I add a box shadow to the left and right sides of every table row?
currently, the box shadow only displaying on the top and bottom of a table row

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:

For the horizontal scrollbar you should add an overflow hidden (which can be overflow-x or overflow-y):

```
<Table sx={{ minWidth: 650, overflow: "hidden" }} aria-label="simple table">
```

For the second question something like this?
https://codepen.io/michalkliment/pen/dWzwEG

Please only ask one question.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. The answer to your question is yes, but my table has a border around it and the shadow box is not working on the left and right sides of every table row. I checked the Codepen link but didn't find a proper solution for my question